# ng-click not working with function in controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Inside my controller, I have the following:

```
$scope.openMenu = function() {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight(true);
    };
```

In my html, I have this:

```
<ion-content class="side-ion-content">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item menu-close href="#/main" class="item item-icon-left" ng-click="openMenu()">
            <i class="icon ion-location"></i>
            <span>Main</span>
          </ion-item>
       </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working.  What am I doing wrong?  Basically, when I click the link, I want it to act as though I am pulling the right side menu.  I am building off of this:  http://codepen.io/heedoo/pen/EarxjZ/

Comment: I can't find `ng-click="openMenu()"` in your codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `href="#/swipe"` and if it works move redirection into `openMenu` function ... like so .. `location.href = '#/swipe'`

Answer (score 0):

Are you completely sure about ng-click not working?

If you haven't done it yet, try to print something into the console with console.log inside your openMenu function.

In my opinion your ng-click event is working and your openMenu is triggered as expected... but you are not changing the classes needed to show/hide the menu.

This may be happening for one of these reasons:
1. You don't have a menu.
2. Your menu is not a RightMenu (try using $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft(true);).

And if this doesn't solve the problem, try to use just:
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
(without the "true" value)... usually "toggling" functions don't need an explicit value to do their job.

GL!

Comment: sorry i got it working.  i had to remove the menu-close and it works.  sorry